# JOSE not found in Visual Studio , how to install/import it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-mobile-services, jose

I started a *Azure Mobile Apps Quick Start* (.NET backend).

I've tried to add `using JOSE;` in my *ApiController* header but it is not found in my Visual Studio:

*(The type or namespace name 'Jose' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))*

I've tried to run *Package Manager Console*:

> PM> Install-Package jose-jwt

Error:

> Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies.
>
> 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' is not compatible with
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0)',  'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
>   3.2.3 constraint: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0)'.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-Package jose-jwt
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

How to fix this? Appreciate for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fixed this myself, but not sure is it a proper solution,

**Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Manage NuGet Package for Solution...**

under Search box type: "**JOSE**"

Choose & Install: "**Xamarin.JOSE.JWT**"